# OSM leafleft JS Getting the center and radius of an editable circle

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap

I am using OSM using layer Leaflet Js.I am trying to edit the circle using the Leaflet.Editable.js. I think, getting the circle and the radius using the 'editable:vertex:dragend' event  is not a right approach. 
Is there any other way to get the circle center and radius after dragging it.
Here is my apprach

```
    <link href="https://leafletjs-cdn.s3.amazonaws.com/content/leaflet/master/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://leafletjs-cdn.s3.amazonaws.com/content/leaflet/master/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="Leaflet.Editable.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    #mapdiv { height: 500px; }
</style>
<div id="mapdiv"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

        var map = L.map('mapdiv', {editable: true}).setView([23.2599333, 77.41261499999996], 13);
        L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
            maxZoom: 30
        }).addTo(map);

        L.EditControl = L.Control.extend({
            options: {
                position: 'topleft',
                callback: null,
                kind: '',
                html: ''
            },

            onAdd: function (map) {
                var container = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'leaflet-control leaflet-bar'),
                    link = L.DomUtil.create('a', '', container);

                link.href = '#';
                link.title = 'Create a new ' + this.options.kind;
                link.innerHTML = this.options.html;
                L.DomEvent.on(link, 'click', L.DomEvent.stop)
                          .on(link, 'click', function () {
                            window.LAYER = this.options.callback.call(map.editTools);
                          }, this);

                return container;
            }

        });


        var circle = L.circle([23.2599333, 77.41261499999996], {radius: 1000}).addTo(map);
        circle.enableEdit();
        circle.on('dblclick', L.DomEvent.stop).on('dblclick', circle.toggleEdit);
        //circle.on('editable:vertex:drag', function (e) {
        map.on('editable:vertex:dragend', function (e) {
            //alert(e.vertex.latlng);
            circle.setLatLng(e.vertex.latlng);
            alert(circle.getRadius());
        });

</script>
```

Any help on this regard or the best approach will be really helpful.

Comment: can you post a full demo of this somewhere?

Comment: Hi @snkashis,
I have edited my post with full code. You can copy & paste this code in a page to see the demo. Please download the "Leaflet.Editable.js" file from "https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.Editable/blob/gh-pages/src/Leaflet.Editable.js" and put it in the same folder to access it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I would suggest using

```
map.on('editable:drawing:move', function (e) {
    console.log(circle.getLatLng())
    console.log(circle.getRadius());
});
```

This works for either dragging the vertex on the outer edge of the circle, or drags of the entire circle from the center marker.